# Select specific rows from MySQL and display in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a script that exports data from my database table, and sends the data in an email.  This all works fine, i just want to slightly change my query so that it only displays the specific rows i want to show. Let's say row 2, 4, 6 etc....

Example database table:

```
+------+--------+--------+
|Number|Language|Date    |
+------+--------+--------+
|1     |text 1  |20/01/14|
+------+--------+--------+
|2     |text 2  |20/01/14|
+------+--------+--------+
|3     |text 3  |20/01/14|
+------+--------+--------+
|4     |text 4  |20/01/14|
+------+--------+--------+
|5     |text 5  |20/01/14|
+------+--------+--------+
|6     |text 6  |20/01/14|
+------+--------+--------+
|7     |text 7  |20/01/14|
+------+--------+--------+
```

The query that i am using at the moment is :

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as `count`, `lang`, DATE(NOW()) as `month_ending`
FROM
    mydata.table
WHERE
    `date` > DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL - 1 MONTH) AND
    `date` < DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY `lang` , DATE(NOW());
```

How could i achieve this as i have no ID's in my table so i can't refer to the rows that way? I also want to keep the date sorting that is already in my query.

Comment: do you mean random rows or exact particular rows?

Comment: exact particular rows

Comment: add one more where condition // and Language in ('text2','text4' ....etc)

Comment: @KarinaMcGourty what do you want exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Add a unique column and limit to it. Do not make it too hard for yourself;-). Your new table will be:

```
+------+------+--------+--------+
|ID    |Number|Language|Date    |
+------+------+--------+--------+
|1     |1     |text 1  |20/01/14|
+------+------+--------+--------+
|2     |2     |text 2  |20/01/14|
+------+------+--------+--------+
|3     |3     |text 3  |20/01/14|
+------+------+--------+--------+
|4     |4     |text 4  |20/01/14|
+------+------+--------+--------+
|5     |5     |text 5  |20/01/14|
+------+------+--------+--------+
|6     |6     |text 6  |20/01/14|
+------+------+--------+--------+
|7     |7     |text 7  |20/01/14|
+------+------+--------+--------+
```

Limit on column ID and you are done!

```
WHERE ID = 1 OR ID = 3 OR ID = 5.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end i just went for this approach, probably not the best but it works! Thanks!

```
SELECT count(*) as `count`, `lang`, DATE(NOW()) as `month_ending` FROM mydata.table WHERE `date`>DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) AND `date`< DATE(NOW()) AND `lang`=("be") OR `lang`=("dk") GROUP BY `lang`, DATE(NOW());
```